# A -1.0 / 1.0 operation returns a 0?

Tags: c

I'm writing a program that solves matrices by Gauss-Jordan method. Everything works except for -1.0/1.0. When printing the matrix, it prints out a 0.0 when it should still be -1.0. Can anyone explain why this is happening? In the case below, matrix[k][s] is -1.0 and the divisor is a 1.0 double value.

```
for(s = 0; s < (n+1); s++){ //Augmented matrix, while s < number of columns

                    if(divisor == 0.0){ //Not dividing by 0.0
                            continue;
                    }

                    matrix[k][s] = matrix[k][s] / divisor;

                    if((matrix[k][s] < TOLERANCE) || (matrix[k][s] < -TOLERANCE)){ //To avoid -0.0 values, TOLERANCE == 1e6
                            matrix[k][s] = 0.0;
                    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not accidentally changing the matrix before printing it out?

Answer (score 6):

My guess is that you wanted this condition:

```
(matrix[k][s] < TOLERANCE) || (matrix[k][s] < -TOLERANCE)
```

to be this:

```
(matrix[k][s] < TOLERANCE) && (matrix[k][s] > -TOLERANCE)
```

In other words, when `fabs(matrix[k][s]) < TOLERANCE`

(Note to explain comments in other answers - I originally used `abs`, but `fabs` is the correct function here.)

Comment: Also, TOLERANCE should probably be 1e-6, not 1e6.

Comment: Even better, you should replace the magical epsilons with some proper analysis...

Comment: `matrix[k][s]` certainly has a FP value. Unlike C++,  `abs(matrix[k][s])` converts to an `int`  causing 0.999 to become 0 and UB when `matrix[k][s]` outside `int` range.  Better to use `fabs(matrix[k][s])` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6602602/2410359).

Answer (score 2):

```
if ((matrix[k][s] < TOLERANCE) || (matrix[k][s] < -TOLERANCE))
```

does not do what you want it to.  In particular, if `matrix[k][s]` is `-1.0`, this condition is true.  Instead, you want:

```
if (fabs(matrix[k][s]) < TOLERANCE)
```

Answer (score 2):

`||` should be `&&` ?

```
if (fabs(matrix[k][s]) < TOLERANCE)
```

Edit ref [`Jon's answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602574/a-1-0-1-0-operation-returns-a-0/6602603#6602603); `abs(matrix[k][s]) < TOLERANCE` is right solution..

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few issues:

1. Isn't that code going to set everything from -infinity **..** TOLERANCE to 0?  That can't really be what you want.
2. Shouldn't TOLERANCE be a very small number?
3. Is the comparison with 0.0 really necessary?  On modern processors, a division by 0 *should* produce an infinity and should *not* produce an exception.
4. You might want to write the division as `matrix[k][s] /= divisor;`